# Downsides to colcon's --symlink-install option in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, build, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any downsides or pitfalls to using the `--symlink-install` option in when building a workspace with `colcon` in ROS2?

To me, it seems like a cross-the-board improvement; symbolic links instead of copies take less disk space, and make for faster development when using `python`, `urdf`, `xacro`, `yaml`, etc; and compiled language files are still handled as expected (to my knowledge). But I feel like I must be missing something, else I would expect `colcon` to enable `--symlink-install` by default if there weren't any downsides.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389401/downsides-to-colcon%27s---symlink-install-option-in-ros2?/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-10-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're just developing on your local machine, there's no down-side and I threw it into my [colcon defaults](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#defaults-yaml) file.

If you're cross-compiling and sending built software to a remote target, you don't need to transport the src, build or log.  The workspace functions just fine with only the install folder as long as you didn't --symlink-install back to src when you built it.

I think it would cause a number of expensive headaches in CI/CD and production deployment if symlink was the default, so personally I think the user-side colcon defaults file is a reasonable compromise.

---

Originally posted by [BrettRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/55733/brettrd/) with karma: 86 on 2021-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-11-03**:
This is definitely a good point that I hadn't considered. I've been pretty focused on my own dev machine, but deployment and CI/CD are definitely important, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the default without symlinking is a more predictable workflow.
You 'compile' everytime. Stuff works.

With symlinking, sometimes stuff works without compiling (Yeah!). But sometimes you rename a python file, and it doesn't work anymore. So you need to be very aware that adding files and modifying filenames do require recompilation. And modifying python and urdf files don't. But modifying cpp files does.

Perhaps not that trivial especially for new users who don't really have a clue yet about how this all works under-the-hood.

---

Originally posted by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) with karma: 80 on 2021-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-11-03**:
Yeah, I can definitely see the value in a more explicit *compile* strategy, especially for newer users. Thanks